# how to retreive lines between specific words by given two files?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have two files 1 and 2. file 1 contains all the detail information of metabolic pathways that start with C and D and its contain large number of C and D while files 2 contains only specif ID line with its name that start with C and have unique  (shortlisted C, less in number). files look like this:

**File 1:**

```
C    00010 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis [PATH:smup00010]
D      SMPSPU_277 pfkA; 6-phosphofructokinase   K00850 pfkA; 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11]
D      SMPSPU_278 gapA; glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase        K00134 GAPDH; glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase [EC:1.2.1.12]
D      SMPSPU_274 acoA; pyruvate dehydrogenase E1 component subunit 
alpha       K00161 PDHA; pyruvate dehydrogenase E1 component alpha subunit 
[EC:1.2.4.1]
D      SMPSPU_172 korA; 2-oxoglutarate ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit alpha  K00174 korA; 2-oxoglutarate/2-oxoacid ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit alpha [EC:1.2.7.3 1.2.7.11]
D      SMPSPU_061 korB; 2-oxoglutarate ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit beta   K00175 korB; 2-oxoglutarate/2-oxoacid ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit beta [EC:1.2.7.3 1.2.7.11]
C    00020 Citrate cycle (TCA cycle) [PATH:smup00020]
D      SMPSPU_201 sucA; 2-oxoglutarate dehydrogenase, E1 component      K00164 OGDH; 2-oxoglutarate dehydrogenase E1 component [EC:1.2.4.2]
D      SMPSPU_120 lpdA; dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase  K00382 DLD; dihydrolipoamide dehydrogenase [EC:1.8.1.4]
D      SMPSPU_172 korA; 2-oxoglutarate ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit alpha  K00174 korA; 2-oxoglutarate/2-oxoacid ferredoxin oxidoreductase subunit alpha [EC:1.2.7.3 1.2.7.11]
D      SMPSPU_169 sucD; succinyl-CoA synthetase subunit alpha   K01902 sucD; succinyl-CoA synthetase alpha subunit [EC:6.2.1.5]
D      SMPSPU_229 pdhB; pyruvate dehydrogenase E1 component subunit beta        K00162 PDHB; pyruvate dehydrogenase E1 component beta subunit [EC:1.2.4.1]
D      SMPSPU_275 pdhC; dihydrolipoamide acyltransferase E2 component   K00627 DLAT; pyruvate dehydrogenase E2 component (dihydrolipoamide acetyltransferase) [EC:2.3.1.12]
C    00030 Pentose phosphate pathway [PATH:smup00030]
D      SMPSPU_057 tktB; transketolase, N-terminal subunit       K00615 E2.2.1.1; transketolase [EC:2.2.1.1]
D      SMPSPU_058 tktA; transketolase, C-terminal subunit       K00615 E2.2.1.1; transketolase [EC:2.2.1.1]
C    00051 Fructose and mannose metabolism [PATH:smup00051]
D      SMPSPU_277 pfkA; 6-phosphofructokinase   K00850 pfkA; 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11]
D      SMPSPU_230 fbaA; fructose-bisphosphate aldolase  K01624 FBA; fructose-bisphosphate aldolase, class II [EC:4.1.2.13]
```

**file 2:**

```
C    00261 Monobactam biosynthesis [PATH:smup00261]
C    00300 Lysine biosynthesis [PATH:smup00300]
C    00660 C5-Branched dibasic acid metabolism [PATH:smup00660]
C    00680 Methane metabolism [PATH:smup00680]
C    02020 Two-component system [PATH:smup02020]
C    02024 Quorum sensing [PATH:smup02024]
```

Now I want to extract only those C and their respective D which are present in file 2.

I tried this script

```
fgrep -f name-C-non-homowba00001 wba00001.keg |grep -E '^C.*PATH|^D' | less
```

but i give me this C id and name files.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `python` matter?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good that you have showed what you have tried to solve your problem. Could you please do edit your post to add sample of input and sample of expected output in brief and clear manner so that we will understand question better.

Comment: Did you tried something? Please edit your post to add code you already wrote!

Comment: Did you add the letters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` only for your explanation? If yes, please state this and also add the exact input in its original format. If the input contains more than one group of lines, please show a longer example input with a few groups. Otherwise it is not clear what would follow the last D line. Do you want all lines C and D if there are several groups? Or only a specific group? Is the number of words/fields in your C line always the same? How do you distinguish between lines C and D? Indentation? Format of the first field? Please add all clarification **to the question**.

Comment: @F.Hauri i wrote the code but when i edit my post and save it, it start given error. i think its formatting issue. i used this website first time. i tried a lot but issue not resolved so i removed it.

Comment: @Bodo This is my original input file that i have given. A,,B, C, D are in the KEGG original file to represent pathways and proteins. i have edited my post and also mentioned there. i have also attached a link of original input file. after the last D line it should follow the next C line that contains PATH in it.

Comment: @Alina python code render well on SO! Try `sed 's/^/    /' yourcode.py`

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to do with the numbers `01054` etc. Do you want to read the numbers from the files and only show the `C` lines that contain any of these numbers and the following `D` lines?

Comment: @Bodo  the number *01054*  shows the specific "C" IDs which are present in both folder 1 and folder 2 files. but the difference is folder 1 files have detail information of that C while the folder 2 only contains its number id.   Yes the above two commands worked but it did not give me the specific C   following D lines which are present in folder 2 files (contains "C" IDs number) e.g. 5000 files like non-homolgous*1.txt

Comment: @Alina Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information. I still don't know if you want to (1) extract **all** `C` lines that contain `PATH` or (2) extract only the `C` lines that contain the numbers from a different file. In case (1) the information about the numbers and the other files would be irrelevant, in case (2) you should explain the details in your question.

Comment: @Bodo Question completely edited. please check

Comment: @Alina You can see that I surrounded the file contents with `~~~lang-none` and `~~~` to format it as a code block. With this, line breaks are shown as you enter them. I guess you added the blank lines to get line breaks in the text output. You should keep the other lines (`A` and `B`)  in your sample input to show how the real data looks like. If you removed these lines intentionally because you remove these lines from the input, then state in the question what you have changed. Please also clarify if the number in the 2nd column is sufficient to identify the `C` lines you want to extract.

Comment: Are the lines in file 2 100%identical to the matching lines in file1. This means spaces, capitals, hyphenation, etc ..

Comment: @kvantour yes its 100% identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
cat input | grep -E '^[CD]' | sed -n '/^C.*PATH/,/^C/p' | uniq -f2 | grep -E '^C.*PATH|^D'
```

where:

- `input` is your file
- first `grep` prints all lines beginning with C or D
- `sed` prints all lines from one beginning with C and containing PATH to next one beginning with C (included)
- `uniq` suppresses all adjacent lines that are equal, except for the first 2 fields
- last `grep` prints all lines beginning with C and containing PATH or beginning with D

Comment: C    02060 Phosphotransferase system (PTS) [PATH:msu02060]    
C    03070 Bacterial secretion system [PATH:msu03070]            
D      MS1563 secD; SecD protein        K03072 secD; preprotein          translocase subunit SecD            
D      MS1564 secF; SecF protein        K03074 secF; preprotein translocase subunit SecF          
D      MS0204 secE; SecE protein        K03073 secE; preprotein translocase subunit SecE  **by using this  script, i got Two consecutive C line which means it didn’t provide D line of first C**

Comment: It solved by adding [D] with sed -n '/^C.*PATH/,/^C[D]/p'

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1!~/^D$/ { select=0; } $1=="C" && $NF~/PATH/ { select=1; } {if(select) print; }' inputfile
```

Explanation:

`$1!~/^D$/ { select=0; }` A line other than `D` stops output.
`$1=="C" && $NF~/PATH/ { select=1; }` A `C` line that contains `PATH` in the last field starts output.
`{if(select) print; }` Print current line if selected for output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a safe method:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$0];next}/^C/{p=($0 in a)}p' file2 file1
```